# How to make Transactions in Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have fragments A>>B>>C>>D>>E. When i traverse from A to B I use the following code

```
Fragment fragment = new B();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "B").addToBackStack("A").commit();
```

and similarly for B to C and ....

How can i traverse from D to A directly without going to C.?

Please any help will be appreciated. Other answers are way to confusing. None is working for me.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What is preventing you from simply creating `new A()` and adding D to the backstack?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this


Fragment fragment = new B();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id. frame_container, fragment).commit(); 




In D

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Fragment fragment = new D();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id. frame_container, fragment).commit(); 
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) of type CheckoutLoggedIn must override or implement a supertype method>>> ERROR

Comment: sorry i cant able to got your point .. will you please brief it ?